# Fill different tableViews inside the different collectionView cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have a complicated situation and I need your help to figure out what should I do.

I have one prototype `UIcollectionView`, this prototype should be created 4 times for each style type. 
I defined these style type as an enum:

```
enum Colors {
    case black, blue, red, green
}

var color = Colors.black
```

Inside of `CollectionViewCell` I have also a `tableView` that has one prototype that contain a label. And there are four arrays that `TableViews` should be filled by these arrays:

```
var black = ["black1","black2","black3"]
var blue = ["blue1","blue2","blue3"]
var red = ["red1","red2","red3"]
var green = ["green1","green2","green3"]
```

now, I tried to make a connection between these TableViews and collectionViews

first for `UICollectionView`

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
switch indexPath.row {
case 0,1,2,3:
    if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "colors", for: indexPath) as? colorsCell {

        switch indexPath.row {
        case 1:
            self.color = .black
        case 2:
            self.color = .blue
        case 3:
            self.color = .red
        case 4:
            self.color = .green
        default:
            break
        }

        return cell
    }
default:
    break
}
return UICollectionViewCell()
```

}

Then, for `TableView`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    switch indexPath.row {
    case 0,1,2,3:
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "colCell", for: indexPath) as? colCellDashboard {
            switch self.color {
            case .black:
                cell.title.text = black[indexPath.row]
            case .blue:
                cell.title.text = blue[indexPath.row]
            case .red:
                cell.title.text = red[indexPath.row]
            case .green:
                cell.title.text = green[indexPath.row]
            }
            return cell
        }
    return UITableViewCell()
}
```

The result isn't good enough, the first three tableview in the first three collectionview were filled by blue array, and the last one is correct that filled with green array.

I will be appreciated if you can help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the tableView is nested inside the collection you should use

```
class CollectionCell:UICollectionViewCell,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

   var tableArr = [String]() // table dataSource array

   func configure(_ res:[String]) {
      tableArr = arr
      self.tableView.reloadData()
   } 

  ///////
  here implement the cellForRowAt and numberOfRows for the nested tableView
}
```

---

Inside the vc that contains the collectionView declare the array like this

```
let arr =  [["black1","black2","black3"] , ["blue1","blue2","blue3"] , 
             ["red1","red2","red3"] ,  ["green1","green2","green3"]]
```

Then inside `cellForItemAt`

```
 if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "colors", for: indexPath) as? colorsCell {
 cell.configure(arr[indexPath.row])
```

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, The issue with you code is that in your `cellForItemAt` delegate method of collection view you are assigning color to a class variable `self.color`. This will be overwritten for each call to the delegate. So when `cellForRowAt` delegate for tableview is called it will have the overwritten value of `self.color` (whatever will be the most updated value) and as a result you will see unexpected entry in your table.

Having tableviews inside collectionViews is kinda common problem. The simplest approach to solve it is:

-Put your datasouce for tableview inside the collectionViewCell.(create a variable in `UICollectionViewCell` subclass.)

-Assign value to your datasource for each tableView inside `cellForItemAt` delegate of CollectionView.

-Write all tableViewDelegates inside collectionViewCell and use the datasource varaible of CollectionViewCell to fill tableView.

The key is to underStand that tableView is inside CollectionViewCell and therefore, your CollectionViewCell is responsible to create the tableView.

The CollectionViewCell Structure given be **@Sh_Khan** looks fine(So not putting similiar code).